# why this Javascript code not working

Tags: javascript, html

Below is simple code I am using. But why it's not working. giving javascript error.

```
function postcommnet(wallid) {
    var txtboxid='commentdata_'+wallid;
    var commentdata=document.getElementById(txtboxid).value
}
```

error is : document.getElementById(txtboxid) is null.

Please help.

Comment: post also the html, it may help

Comment: sorry>, but this information is not enough to help you

Comment: Html is dynamically generating textboxes

Comment: It means there is no element with ID `'commentdata_'+wallid` (whatever `wallid` is). Your code is correct, the DOM just does not have such an element.

Comment: well, apparently your textbox with id 'commentdata_' + wallid doesn't exist

Comment: Could it be that commentdata_x does not exist? Where x is the number within wallid. I would also recommend jQuery, it makes the job easier. E.g. $("#commentdata_"+wallid).value();

Comment: @raRaRa: really?  Importing a full library so that you can type `$` instead of `document.getElementById`?  There are things that JQuery makes measurably easier, but this is not one (Since you can't get easier than 1 line with a standard function that requires no edge-cases)...  Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few cases where the error is telling you what's wrong:

"document.getElementById(txtboxid) is null."

This means, essentially, that the value of the above is `null`. This means that getElementById did not find an element with the ID you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the value of `txtboxid` is correctly an id on one of the DOM's elements. Your error message means that the element is not retrieved and thus the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the element with the id. I have checked the code is working if there is an element with the given id.

This actually works:

```
<html>
<body>
<input value="lol" id="commentdata_1"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function postcomment(wallid) { var txtboxid='commentdata_'+wallid;

var commentdata=document.getElementById(txtboxid).value

}
postcomment(1);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id may not exist on your page, its worth checking.

The following checks to see if the id exists. If it does not exist it will tell you the id its trying to use.

> function postcommnet(wallid) {

```
    var txtboxid='commentdata_'+wallid;

    if(document.getElementById(txtboxid)){
        var commentdata=document.getElementById(txtboxid).value 
    } 
    else{ 
        alert('the id - ' + txtboxid +' does not exist'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Firefox/Firebug and setting a breakpoint inside your function, then check that the value for `wallid` is what you expect and, if necessary, examine the live HTML to ensure that the element does, in fact, exist.